# Self join without grouping using analytics

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, self-join

I am creating a program with the objective of returning the first record meeting a set of conditions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_ACCOUNTS AS 
SELECT 
A.ID,
A.BALANCE,
A.PRODUCTCODE,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCOUNTS A2 WHERE A.CUSTOMERID=A2.CUSTOMERID) CUSTOMER_NUM_ACCOUNTS
FROM ACCOUNTS A
```

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM V_ACCOUNTS WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND PRODUCTID = 467 AND CUSTOMER_NUM_ACCOUNTS > 2
```

Is this possible to enhance the above query so I avoid the self-join on the same table? Can i use analytics with a condition? 
Performance is an issue and I would like to optimize the query as much as possible.

Comment: What makes a row "first"? Do you understand that tables have no order, and rownums without ORDER BY are arbitrary? PS Please give a [mce]. Also, if you know a productid then you should put it in the same query that you count in so the DBMS doesn't have to count rows for other productids. That alone should allow the optimizer to eliminate any implementation effort from this self-join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` analytic function might help:

```
create or replace view v_accounts as 
  select 
    a.id,
    a.balance,
    a.productcode,
    count(*) over (partition by a.customerid) customer_num_accounts
from accounts a
```

Comment: Yes! exactly what I was looking for. Thanks